# ejabberd 18.06 http:request error failed_connect

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I m sending an HTTP request from my custom module in ejabberd 18.06

I have tried multiple server addresses where my API is available to receive request and CURL is working on same server.

I receive error while connecting to server. I have tried multiple options but couldn't succeed. Any Help ??

```
Sep = "&",
Header = [],
ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
Post = [
    "user_id=", To, Sep,
    "message_from=", From, Sep,
    "message_type=AC", Sep
],
HTTPOptions = [],
Options = [],
{ok, _ReqId} = httpc:request(post, {Url, Header, ContentType, list_to_binary(Post)}, HTTPOptions, [ {sync, false} ]),
```

> {http,{#Ref<0.553383904.99614721.184438>,{error,{failed_connect,[{to_address,{<<"localhost">>,443}},{inet,[inet],{options,{socket_options,[inet,{packet_size,0},{packet,0},{header,0},{active,false},{mode,binary}]}}}]}}}}

Comment: What is the value of the `Url` variable?

Comment: @legoscia its the API URL in current case "https://localhost/webdem/api.php"

Comment: @legoscia I have tested with http://myserveturl.com/publicapi/api.php